# How to test a function using Jest and Enzyme in React TDD

Tags: reactjs, tdd, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function in my component which looks something like this:

```
toggleFilter = (type, name) => {
        const filterApplied = this.state.appliedFilterList[type].includes(name);

        if (filterApplied) {
            //Remove the applied filter
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                appliedFilterList: {
                    ...prevState.appliedFilterList,
                    [type]: prevState.appliedFilterList[type].filter(filter => filter !== name)
                }
            }));
        } else {
            //Add the filter
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                appliedFilterList: {
                    ...prevState.appliedFilterList,
                    [type]: [...prevState.appliedFilterList[type], name]
                }
            }));
        }
    };
```

where **appliedFilterList** is an object and looks something like:

```
appliedFilterList: {
                a: [],
                b: [],
                t: []
            },
```

So,I am trying to write a test case for this function using Jest and Enzyme like this:

```
it("checks toggleFilter function", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <ProductList
                headerText="Hello World"
                productList={data}
                paginationSize="10"
                accessFilters={["a 1", "a 2"]}
                bandwidthFilters={["b 1", "b 2"]}
                termsFilters={["t 1", "t 2"]}
                appliedFilterList={appliedFilter}
            />
        );
        expect(wrapper.instance().toggleFilter()).toBe(true);
    });
```

where **data** and **appliedFilter** are 2 arrays that i have created with hardcoded values.

The test case fails and gives an error saying **TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined at toggleFilter**.

I have tried as much as i can to figure out a way to test this function but I am not able to. Can someone please help me with this? I am struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

`toggleFilter` is supposed to be take two arguments. You are not passing in any in your test `expect(wrapper.instance().toggleFilter())`. That's what's causing the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for the late reply.I just tried to pass the arguments to the function in my filter as you mentioned in and it looks like `expect(wrapper.instance().toggleFilter("access", "a"))toEqual("a")` but I get an error  saying `Expected "a" , Received undefined`. Can you please check and tell me how to proceed.

Comment: The function `toggleFilter` is not returning anything. `expect(...).toEqual(...)` is checking the returned value. You can either change your function to return some value. Or you can call the function and then check in the state in an `expect()` in the next line. You might find this helpful - http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/state.html.